# Is Plague of Toads as unhelpfull as it seems?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-witch-doctor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does my Plague of Toads make me croak?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67623/why-does-my-plague-of-toads-make-me-croak)

So far I've been using the Witchdoctor's Corpse Spider skill as my bread-n-butter kill-stuff spammer, and it has worked very well.

Recently I've unlocked the Plague of Toads skill which does considerably more damage (130% per toad rather than 16% per spider)

However the toads don't go where I click, they are simply released and seem to meander about in the general direction of the click. I can easily fill and area of my choice with a dozen or more spiders, I cannot easily do the same with my toads. Do the toads have a large AOE with their explosion? What justifies their usefullness if I can't really specify their target?

Many Spiders, Small Area.
[image: Skitter! Skitter! Skitter!]

Few Toads, Large Area.
[image: Ribbit! Ribbit! Ribbit!]

Both Tests were done in a similar fasion, I clicked an area and released my swarms many times and received these different results.

Comment: Try using it at melee range. It's a close range spell, like Shock Pulse.

Comment: @Wipqozn any input as to why my comment was deleted?